# Are iSeries AS/400 (DB2?), Lotus 1-2-3, and Excel date/time formats the same?

Tags: db2, excel, date-format, db2-10.5

Are the formats for dates/times from AS/400, to Lotus 1-2-3 that carried over into excel...with the [date being the number of days since 1900-1-1 when mistaking 1900 for a leap year](http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/excel-date-conversion-days-from-1900) as an integer, and the decimal portion [being the time](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time).

Are they all the same format?

Comment: Why do you care? What problem are you trying to solve with the knowledge of the internal storage format?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have a database I'm working on with that internal storage format...it's not stored as a date though, it's stored as two fields with 6 digits each one marked time and one marked date.  But it's not the native DB2 date / time stamp...

Comment: I figure at some point maybe people pulled stuff out of it and converted it in excel or lotus 1-2-3 and that's why it's stored like that.

Comment: If you pull the data out of DB2 you will be using SQL, so you don't need to know how DB2 stores it. And I very much doubt you would write Excel or Lotus files manually byte by byte but using a library which handles that.

Comment: Well it wasn’t my idea, I didn’t build the database, I’m just querying it; and I have no intention of altering it or the processes that record it’s records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Db2 for i (aka AS/400) dates are stored internally as a Scaliger number (aka [Julian Day number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day))

The number of days since noon on Monday, January 1, 4713 BC.

```
select hex(current_date)
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

returns `002583EC` as of about 3pm MDT April 30,2019

The decimal value is 2,458,604

Which agrees which the *current value* on the web page linked to above
[image: screen shot from Julian day page]

Comment: Okay so AS/400 dates are not stored like that.  But Lotus and Excel are?

Comment: @leeand00. Yes, Excel/L123 store dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day (ddddd.tttttt) so same **type** of number but using a different base date.

Comment: @topshot I believe there's something about it here: https://superuser.com/questions/736182/how-does-excel-handle-the-hmmss-format/736190#736190

Comment: @leeand00 Yep, the cpearson page from that answer is where I found the info in fact. ;)